# Fill in missing rows in data in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
1     8

2    12

3     2

5    -6

6     1

8     5
```

I want to add a row in the places where the 4 and 7 would have gone in the first column and have the second column for these new rows be 0, so adding these rows:

```
4     0

7     0
```

I have no idea how to do this in R.
In excel, I could use a vlookup inside an iferror. Is there a similar combo of functions in R to make this happen?

Edit: also, suppose that row 1 was missing and needed to be filled in similarly. Would this require another solution? What if I wanted to add rows until I reached ten rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tidyr::complete` to fill in the missing sequence between `min` and `max` values.

```
library(tidyr)
library(rlang)

complete(df, V1 = min(V1):max(V1), fill = list(V2 = 0))
#Or using `seq`
#complete(df, V1 = seq(min(V1), max(V1)), fill = list(V2 = 0))

#     V1    V2
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1     8
#2     2    12
#3     3     2
#4     4     0
#5     5    -6
#6     6     1
#7     7     0
#8     8     5
```

If we already know min and max of the dataframe we can use them directly. Let's say we want data from `V1 = 1`  to 10, we can do.

```
complete(df, V1 = 1:10, fill = list(V2 = 0))
```

---

If we don't know the column names beforehand, we can do something like :

```
col1 <- names(df)[1]
col2 <- names(df)[2]

complete(df, !!sym(col1) := 1:10, fill = as.list(setNames(0, col2)))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L), V2 = c(8L, 12L, 
2L, -6L, 1L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Works great! My only issue now is if I don't have the column names V1 and V2, what do I use instead? My guesses of df[,1] and df[,2] or .[,1] and .[,2] don't work.

Comment: @AnthonyH You can change `V1` to the column name that you have. Or you don't know what would be column names beforehand?

Comment: Well, I want to do this in a for loop on multiple pairs of columns in a df, so I need to use the iteration number as I go.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. the error is "could not find function 'sym'". It's all good though, I'm just going to name the columns as I go. Thanks!

Comment: `sym` is in `rlang`, you need to run `library(rlang)`.